# Не загружаются файлы посредством класса DownloadManager

Tags: android, virtualbox

Требуется загрузить из интернета файл. Для этого использую класс DownloadManager. Код функции:

```
public void download(String filename)
{
    String url = ServerURL+filename;
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name-of-the-file.ext");

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

}
```

Но при загрузке файла в LogCat появляется сообщение "Aborting request for download: download was requested to not use the current network type" и файл висит как загружаемый. Работу приложения проверяю на android`e, установленном на virtualbox. Интернет соединение работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

1. В манифесте прописан permission на интернет?
2. В манифесте прописан permission на запись файлов?
3. Не знаю как работает DownloadMaster, но попробовал бы запустить его в AsyncTask

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Ну и DwonloadManager и так асинхронный

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что android, запущенный на эмуляторе, сетевое подключение воспринимает как *wifi network*. В противном случае (*mobile network*), на *DownloadManager* действуют ограничения по максимальному размеру скачиваемого файла (*DownloadManager.getMaxBytesOverMobile*), и, если размер скачиваемого файла превышает этот лимит, запрос на скачивание будет поставлен в очередь и будет ожидать появления WiFi.

Comment: Сетевое подключение у меня андроид воспринимает как Ethernet. Как сделать иначе я не знаю. Размер скачиваемого файла - пара килобайт, так что проблема максимального размера не может быть.